# Use MYSQLi Prepared Statement to display Data on HTML Table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

I want to use a mysqli prepared statement to display data into an html table.However when I run the code I get a blank page. The code is presented below.

```html
<?php

include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';

?>
<?php

  if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id first_name  second_name , request , purpose, description
                                       FROM data_centre_users WHERE status <> 'approved'")){
   
   $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();
        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($id , $first_name, $second_name ,$request , $purpose , $description );
 
  
function myDate($x){
         
   if ( !strtotime($x)) {
  return "00-00-0000 00:00:00";
   }
    else{
  return strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
               strtotime($x));
     }
  return "";
}         


?>

<section id="content">

<div class="scroll-table">
<table >
<caption>
           
            </caption>
             <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="center"><strong>Name</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Request</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Purpose</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Description</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Approve</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Delete</strong></th>
            </tr>
           </thead>
            <?php
            if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
                // output data of each row
                while($stme->fetch()){ ?>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $first_name."  ".$last_name; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $request; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $purpose; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $description; ?></td>
                        <td class="center" ><a href="javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you want to approve?')){ location.href='approve.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>'; }">approve</a></td>
                        <td class="center" ><a href="javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')){ location.href='deny.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>'; }">deny</a></td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
                        
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?> 
</table>
</div>
</section>

 <?php } ?>
 

<?php

 ?>
```

This is the code for the database connection.

```html
<?php

include_once 'psl-config.php';   // Needed because functions.php is not included
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Unable to connect to MySQL");
    exit();
}
```

This is the script for the table.

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_centre_users` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `request` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `purpose` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `booking_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `access_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `exit_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'not yet',
  `approved_by` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `accessed_by` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `time_approved` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `task_completed` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `time_completed` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `time_started` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `department` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `unit` varchar(140) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=76 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `data_centre_users`
--

INSERT INTO `data_centre_users` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `request`, `purpose`, `description`, `booking_time`, `access_time`, `exit_time`, `status`, `approved_by`, `accessed_by`, `time_approved`, `task_completed`, `time_completed`, `time_started`, `department`, `unit`) 


VALUES
(6, 'kazare', 'Jaguar', 'rautine maintenance', 'Unofficial', 'dust and clean', '2015-08-07 04:34:12.000000', '2015-08-10 02:50:00.000000', '1970-01-01 01:00:00.000000', 'approved', 'SYSTEM', 'Staff', '2015-08-10 09:22:09.000000', 'completed', '2015-08-13 09:30:57.000000', '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000', '', ''),
```

When I run the code I get a blank (empty) page.

After adding the following code to the php.ini file from this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) , 
'ini_set('display_errors', 1);'
'ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);'
'error_reporting(E_ALL);'

The following error is displayed.

```
Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\wamp\www\datacentre\admin\includes\db_connect.php on line 4
```

Any help.

Comment: You have to check out `php_error_log` for error messages.

Comment: Need `comma` to seperate column name `if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id ,first_name  ,second_name, `

Comment: @mapek how do I check the error log

Comment: @Staty thanks for the observation , did the correction but still have the same problem

Comment: @faisalabdulai Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel

Comment: when I add the error reporting to the php.ini file , it gives an error. The error has been added.